# When does excel use a single item from a named range v.s. all the items?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, named-ranges

Say you have the following named-ranges a, b, c, in column A, B, and C:

```
   |A  |B  |C
---+---+---+---------
1  |a  |b  |c 
---+---+---+---------
2  |1  |=a |=b+a
---+---+---+---------
3  |2  |=a |=b+a
---+---+---+---------
4  |3  |=a |=CONCATENATE(b+a)
---+---+---+---------
5  |4  |=a |=MIN(a)
```

then `B4=3` and `C4="33"` for instance are calculated from a single cell in their named-range reference. `C5=1` on the other hand is calculated using the whole range over `a`.

I would like to know where this behavior is defined and how can I know when and how it is used. Is this a case-by-case type of thing or is the behavior well-defined?

Comment: Useful: https://exceljet.net/glossary/implicit-intersection

Comment: @BigBen From the article: "Typically, it happens when a range or array is passed into a formula meant to display a single result in a single cell." I might be nitpicking, but `SUM` falls under the category of "displaying a single result in a single cell", although sourced from multiple cells. Should it not rather be "formula with arguments meant to be single cells"? Cool, so if it's function dependent, do you by chance know I can find a list of all such functions (along with which of the arguments are single-celled).

Comment: I agree with you, that description isn't the greatest. Implicit intersection isn't *exactly* function-dependent though. For example, `SUM` can be used with implicit intersection in a table, or it can be used without implicit intersection in a CSE formula. I don't know of such a list then.

Comment: Would you say it's safe to say that all these type of functions are the same functions that can be passed to subtotal? Or am I missing a bunch of them? https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-subtotal-function

Comment: No it can't be, `MEDIAN` is missing from that list, maybe these are the full collection (or at least Libre's full collection): https://github.com/LibreOffice/core/blob/330df37c7e2af0564bcd2de1f171bed4befcc074/sc/inc/pvfundlg.hrc

Comment: Okay, I think I got most of these functions by properly examining the LibreOffice source code. I wrote it up as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer, or at least captured a large collection of the answer. It seems like the single-item behaviour works on functions that has arguments that are single-variable like (so no ranges or vectors).

To find these functions, I wrote a script that inspects some files from the LibreOffice source code, and try to map all the Excel functions (that are listed by the project) with arrays or ranges as arguments.

Here's the script: https://gist.github.com/heetbeet/64cdfce26c2e4420ed416028b1d22393

And here's the output. All functions are listed with single-item arguments left blank, and multi-item arguments filled with their abbreviated type:

```
AGGREGATE ( □, □, RX, … )
AND ( RX, … )
AVEDEV ( RX, … )
AVERAGE ( RX, … )
AVERAGEA ( RX, … )
CHISQ.TEST ( VA, … )
CHITEST ( VA, … )
CORREL ( VA, … )
COUNT ( RX, … )
COUNTA ( RX, … )
COVAR ( VA, … )
COVARIANCE.P ( VA, … )
COVARIANCE.S ( VA, … )
DEVSQ ( RX, … )
F.TEST ( VA, … )
FORECAST ( □, VA, … )
FORECAST.ETS ( □, VA, □, … )
FORECAST.ETS.CONFINT ( □, VA, □, … )
FORECAST.ETS.SEASONALITY ( □, VA, □, … )
FORECAST.ETS.STAT ( □, VA, □, … )
FORECAST.LINEAR ( □, VA, … )
FREQUENCY ( RA, … )
FTEST ( VA, … )
FVSCHEDULE ( □, RX )
GCD ( RX, … )
GEOMEAN ( RX, … )
GROWTH ( RA, RA, RA, □ )
HARMEAN ( RX, … )
IMPRODUCT ( RX, … )
IMSUM ( RX, … )
INDEX ( RA, □, … )
INTERCEPT ( VA, … )
IRR ( RA, □ )
ISREF ( RX )
KURT ( RX, … )
LARGE ( RX, □ )
LCM ( RX, … )
LINEST ( RA, RA, □, … )
LOGEST ( RA, RA, □, … )
LOOKUP ( □, RA, … )
MATCH ( □, RX, □ )
MAX ( RX, … )
MAXA ( RX, … )
MDETERM ( VA )
MEDIAN ( RX, … )
MIN ( RX, … )
MINA ( RX, … )
MINVERSE ( VA )
MIRR ( RA, □, … )
MMULT ( VA, … )
MODE ( VA, … )
MODE.MULT ( VA, … )
MODE.SNGL ( VA, … )
MULTINOMIAL ( RX, … )
NETWORKDAYS ( □, □, RX, □, … )
NETWORKDAYS.INTL ( □, □, □, RX )
NPV ( □, RX, … )
OR ( RX, … )
PEARSON ( VA, … )
PERCENTILE ( RX, □ )
PERCENTILE.EXC ( RX, □ )
PERCENTILE.INC ( RX, □ )
PERCENTRANK ( RX, □, □ )
PERCENTRANK.EXC ( RX, □, □ )
PERCENTRANK.INC ( RX, □, □ )
PROB ( VA, VA, □, … )
PRODUCT ( RX, … )
QUARTILE ( RX, □ )
QUARTILE.EXC ( RX, □ )
QUARTILE.INC ( RX, □ )
RSQ ( VA, … )
SERIESSUM ( □, □, □, RX )
SKEW ( RX, … )
SKEW.P ( RX, … )
SLOPE ( VA, … )
SMALL ( RX, □ )
STDEV ( RX, … )
STDEV.P ( RX, … )
STDEV.S ( RX, … )
STDEVA ( RX, … )
STDEVP ( RX, … )
STDEVPA ( RX, … )
STEYX ( VA, … )
SUM ( RX, … )
SUMPRODUCT ( VA, … )
SUMSQ ( RX, … )
SUMX2MY2 ( VA, … )
SUMX2PY2 ( VA, … )
SUMXMY2 ( VA, … )
T.TEST ( VA, VA, □, … )
TREND ( RA, RA, RA, □ )
TRIMMEAN ( RX, □ )
TTEST ( VA, VA, □, … )
TYPE ( VX )
VAR ( RX, … )
VAR.P ( RX, … )
VAR.S ( RX, … )
VARA ( RX, … )
VARP ( RX, … )
VARPA ( RX, … )
WORKDAY ( □, □, RX, □, … )
WORKDAY.INTL ( □, □, □, RX )
XIRR ( RX, RX, □ )
XNPV ( □, RX, RX )
XOR ( RX, … )
Z.TEST ( RX, □, … )
ZTEST ( RX, □, … )
```